# python overflowerror on long integer when run on a 32bit raspberry pi

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, raspberry-pi

I have a script I'm trying to get working on my RPi. It works as expected on a 64bit system, but not on 32. I get

OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long

Here is the script

```
for number in xrange(int("0101010101"), int("9898989898")+1):
    number = `number`.zfill(10)
    prev = ''
    i = 0
    for c in `number`:
            if c in prev:
                    break
            else:
                    i += 1
                    prev = c
            if i>=len(`number`):
                    print number
```

I can do this fine with perl but can't figure out how to accomplish with python

Here is the perl equivalent

```
my $num = "";
for $num ("0101010101" .. "0101989898"){
    if ($num =~ /00|11|22|33|44|55|66|77|88|99/o) {
            ++$num;}
    else {
            print "$num\n";}}
```

Also Tried writing it with python3 but I'm completely unfamiliar with 3

Comment: The code doesn't even run properly for me.  Are you sure you want `"number".zfill(10)"`?  (padding the string `number`)?

Comment: yes with out it 0101010101 prints as 101010101. Want to keep it 10 digits. I just copied/pasted the code I posted in the python interpreter to make sure I didn't make a typo and it runs fine for me so not sure why it won't run for you.

Comment: I wasn't sure if it was a semantic error

Answer (score 2):

You can look at the Python Docs for reference.

**CPython implementation detail**: xrange() is intended to be simple and fast. Implementations may impose restrictions to achieve this. The C implementation of Python restricts all arguments to native C longs (“short” Python integers), and also requires that the number of elements fit in a native C long. If a larger range is needed, an alternate version can be crafted using the itertools module: islice(count(start, step), (stop-start+step-1+2*(step<0))//step). http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#xrange

Comment: I think I'm just too stupid for python. perls syntax just always makes sense. I'm messing around with itertools but can't figure out how to format everything. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: I figured it out using intertools.count Thanks again for the help

Comment: Don't get discouraged, while learning it happened every-time, just a matter of knowing language related things. Not posted complete answer, because you can learn by yourself, only by experimenting. You can accept answer, if it really helped.